# Android send udp when phone sleep

Tags: java, android, udp

I have application which must send data when phone is sleeping. This application should use Wifi or 3G. How do this without user action?

Comment: you mean at the moment when phone goes asleep or periodically while sleeping?

Comment: @user1873880 I think about all cases.

Comment: you need to check out android's AlarmManager - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to send data periodically while the phone is sleeping, start a thread. It will continue running when the app is sent to the background.  Or better, create a service if your data is very important.  Services have priority over threads.

The phone will automatically select which network to use (ie. 3g/4g if available, network if not)